# The old lady says "I liked marbles and tops." What is tops?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

An old lady talks about what she would do when she was young. [101 year old](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69HgC2KghBc) (see:2:08-02:12)

She says: **"I liked marbles and tops."**

I looked up both words and I found **"marbles"** and it makes sense. But, **"tops"** do not seem to be the name of a game or anything like that.

I looked it up on **Cambridge, Collins and Merriem webster** and no entry sits well with it. The closest one is related to the name of a card or a card type.

Is that what she means?

Comment: The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/top) entry for **top** includes a picture and link to their entry for [**spinning top.**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spinning-top) Or, noting that *marbles* are "playthings, toys", you could just google **tops playthings**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A top is a spinning toy. Basically you just spin the handle and then release it. Some tops, such as dreidels, have symbols they can land on, and these symbols can be used as a randomizing element in games.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top

Tops are still manufactured and used today, but their popularity has waned somewhat because they are much simpler and more primitive than modern electronics.